# Run Update statement on information_schema.COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, information-schema

A previous dba made many spurious design decisions when creating the schema for the database that I am now administering.  Basically every column in the database that has a default value also is not nullable.  This plays havoc with just about any ORM.  I'd like to be able to run an update statement on the COLUMNS table of the information_schema database and set nullable to YES if the column has a default value, but naturally, I don't have access to that table, nor does root.  Is this even possible, or do I need to manually alter thousands of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Without root privileges or no other way to modify the columns (other than manully touching each column) you could do the following:

1. get a backup of the database
2. restore the backup to a new database that you have **full** access to
3. make the changes to the newly restored database
4. delete the original
5. rename the restored database to the original databases name

I would do this a few times in your dev environment first and feel very confident of the changes before doing it in a production environment.

Also, depending on the size of your database this could be quite an expensive action to perform on the database. If it takes hours or days to run then this might not be a viable solution.

Good luck.

Comment: But I do have root privileges.  I have complete access with grant option on my user, and from the console on the server I can get root access to the database, but I can't grant myself privileges on the information schema database or modify it.